# How to create a custom UIPopover for iphone using monotouch framewok

Tags: iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, uipopover

Here is the question
I need to create a panel that apear on the app by clicking on the naviagationItemRightBarButton.
this panel contains labels btn etc...
I tried to do it using a UIPopover but I think that only works for ipad app.

```
public UIPopoverController CustomPopover;
 FilterSortController newpanel = new FilterSortController();
 //FilterSortController is UIViewController
CustomPopover = new UIPopoverController(newpanel);
CustomPopover.PresentFromBarButtonItem (this.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem , UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, true);
```

and after that I overried the ViewDidLoad of the FilterSortController

```
ContentSizeForViewInPopover = new System.Drawing.SizeF(320,110);
```

There is no way to create a Popover for iphone using monotouch.
thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIPopoverController is not supported on iPhone.  You would have to write your own custom controller and view to get this functionality.  There is a open source implementation in ObjC [here](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover) which you could btouch or port.

Comment: Thanks for this implemen.
it is not well maked
I am looking for something for monotouch to custom is like I want
Can you just give me the main idea how to do it

Comment: I would upvote twice just for the effort vs expectation of getting any points for the answer. :)